# How expensive would this function be to call with every log message in a Java/Kotlin application?

Tags: java, performance, kotlin

The code is

```
 private fun inferTag(): String =
        Throwable().stackTrace
            .getOrElse(CALL_STACK_INDEX) {
                throw IllegalStateException("Synthetic stacktrace didn't have enough elements")
            }
            .let {
                val className =
                    ANONYMOUS_CLASS_PATTERN.matcher(it.className)
                        .takeIf(Matcher::find)
                        ?.replaceAll("")
                        ?: it.className

                "[${Thread.currentThread().name}] " +
                    "${className.substringAfterLast(".")}#${it.methodName}:${it.lineNumber}"
            }
```

The idea is that it gets the origin of the caller with every log, so that we do not need to tag our logs with the calling class. Wondering how expensive this would be if you had say 1000 logs

Comment: Have you considered just adding this code, and profiling?

Comment: You should mostly not be logging in production code except for errors, so generally the performance impact shouldn't be a concern.

Comment: @Tenfour04 That's not my experience at all… Of course, things should be logged at an appropriate level, so you can control how much you see from any subsystem. And it's not useful to flood the logs with too much info. But occasional info messages can help to see exactly how a system is configured, when it runs background tasks, and when important events occur. And it can be _really_ helpful to log more detailed info at debug/fine levels, so you can enable that as needed to track down tricky issues. (Frameworks like Spring Boot Actuator let you update log levels while running.)

Comment: Logging frameworks I've used already know the name of the method (and hence class) from which the log is made, so you should be able to display that without any extra coding.